# How to use variables set in an actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am having problems understanding how to use an actionlistener to change the value of variables.

In my program I need to store the choices the user makes by selecting some radio buttons.

I have got a main class with a card layout, then several classes which each are different panels. In one of the panels I have some radio buttons, with an actionlistener as an inner class.

When I try to print the variable value in the main class, it is printed immediately, before the user has made a choice, as I instantiate the panel class and get the variable from it I get the variable before it has been changed by the user.

I know I should not think in a linear manner with Java, but how can I make sure that I fetch the variable after it has been changed by the user and not before? I will not be able to do that will I? I understand there is some flaw in my thinking but I haven't slept properly for ages and I just cannot get my head around this.

```
public class Screen3 extends JPanel{

JRadioButton addition = new JRadioButton("Addition");
JRadioButton subtraction = new JRadioButton("Subtraction");
JRadioButton multiplication = new JRadioButton("Multiplication");
JRadioButton division = new JRadioButton("Division");
JRadioButton all = new JRadioButton("All");

JRadioButton single = new JRadioButton("Single");
JRadioButton two = new JRadioButton("Double");
JRadioButton triple = new JRadioButton("Triple");
JRadioButton mix = new JRadioButton("Mix");

JRadioButton five = new JRadioButton("5");
JRadioButton ten = new JRadioButton("10");

private int type, digit, rounds;

public Screen3() {

JPanel firstButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel secondButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    ButtonGroup myFirstGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup mySecondGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    myFirstGroup.add(addition);
    myFirstGroup.add(subtraction);
    myFirstGroup.add(multiplication);
    myFirstGroup.add(division);
    //myFirstGroup.add(all);

    mySecondGroup.add(single);
    mySecondGroup.add(two);
    mySecondGroup.add(triple);
    //mySecondGroup.add(mix);

    firstButtonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    firstButtonPanel.add(addition);
    firstButtonPanel.add(subtraction);
    firstButtonPanel.add(multiplication);
    firstButtonPanel.add(division);
    //firstButtonPanel.add(all);

    secondButtonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    secondButtonPanel.add(single);
    secondButtonPanel.add(two);
    secondButtonPanel.add(triple);
    //secondButtonPanel.add(mix);

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    buttons.add(selectionLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttons.add(firstButtonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttons.add(secondButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

ButtonGroup myThirdGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JPanel endButtons = new JPanel();

    myThirdGroup.add(five);
    myThirdGroup.add(ten);

    endButtons.add(five);
    endButtons.add(ten);

    endPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    endPanel.add(rounds, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    endPanel.add(endButtons, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

Selection sn = new Selection();

    addition.addActionListener(sn);
    subtraction.addActionListener(sn);
    multiplication.addActionListener(sn);
    division.addActionListener(sn);

    single.addActionListener(sn);
    two.addActionListener(sn);
    triple.addActionListener(sn);

    five.addActionListener(sn);
    ten.addActionListener(sn);
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public int getDigit() {
    return digit;
}

public int getRounds() {
    return rounds;
}

public class Selection implements ActionListener {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(addition.isSelected()) { 
            type = 1;
        }
        else if(subtraction.isSelected()) {
            type = 2;
        }
        else if(multiplication.isSelected())
            type = 3;
        else if(division.isSelected())
            type = 4;
        //else if(all.isSelected())
            //type = 5;

        if(single.isSelected()) {
            digit = 1;
            System.out.println("single");
        }
        else if(two.isSelected())
            digit = 2;
        else if(triple.isSelected())
            digit = 3;

        if(five.isSelected())
            rounds = 5;
        else if(ten.isSelected())
            rounds = 10;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the main class:

```
public class Driver {

public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Math Game");

public JPanel screens = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

int digit = 1;
int rounds = 1;
int type = 1;

Driver() {

}

public void show() {

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");
    JButton previous = new JButton("Previous");
    buttonPanel.add(previous);
    buttonPanel.add(next);

    Screen1 screen1 = new Screen1();  
    Screen2 screen2 = new Screen2();
    Screen3 screen3 = new Screen3();

    screens.add(screen1, "welcome");
    screens.add(screen2, "next");
    screens.add(screen3, "selection");

    frame.add(screens);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(screens.getLayout());
            cl.next(screens);
        }
    });

    previous.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(screens.getLayout());
            cl.previous(screens);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Driver dr = new Driver();
            dr.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I just try a test print of System.out.println(screen3.getType()); either in show() or main

Comment: Would you post relevant sample code? Have you researched any code samples?

Comment: Why add an actionlistener if the user has to (or not!! depending on his choice) tick multiple radio button? Why not add a button that says "Send form/information/Finished" and insert an actionlistener there?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I have added code above. I have done a lot of research but still cannot understand it properly.

Comment: ??? Where is your variable value? You print it in your main class, where is your main class? How do you print? What do you print? I don't think anybody reading this even understands what the goal is of your application. Please be more clear...

Comment: @Joetjah Does that make a difference to my problem though? When I instantiate the class above it will still be instantiated immediately whether there are multiple radio buttons to tick or not.

Comment: It's just that you say something is instantiated immediately. I don't know what 'it' is, what output you try to create nor how your program looks like. I also might be missing something completely...

Comment: @Joetjah I have added the main class above

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when you run the file and do `.show()`, one of the three actionlisteners gets triggered?

Comment: No, show() creates and displays the gui, it has two actionlisteners for showing the next or previous screen. It's the actionlistener in class Screen3 that needs to run in order to change the value of the variable. But I think modality as described below could be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `JOptionPane`/`JDialog` which has [modality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Have a read on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

In example *here* is only printed after `JDialog` is closed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JDialog jd = new JDialog();
            jd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jd.setModal(true);
            jd.pack();
            jd.setVisible(true);

            System.out.println("Here");
        }
    });
}
```

In this example *here* is only printed after `JOptionPane` is closed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JLabel("Hello, world!"));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Panel Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            System.out.println("Here");
        }
    });
}
```

> I know I should not think in a linear manner with Java, but how can I
>   make sure that I fetch the variable after it has been changed by the
>   user and not before?

After using a modal `JDialog`/`JOptionPane` you would simply use public *getters* to access the variable contained within the class instance:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       X x= new X();//will only return after dialog closed

       System.out.println(x.getY());
    }
}

class X {

    private int y=0;//will be assigned during dialog/joptionpanes life span

    public X() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //creates and shows the modal dialog/optionpane which will allow modification of variable y through some input/controls
            }
       });
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a good idea. Although I am not really sure how to structure it, if I have got a frame with several different panels (screens) in a card layout, so that some panels will be shown before the panel where I am changing the variable value that I need to change from user input. Is it a bad idea to use a card layout in this case? Would it be better to let all the panels be dialogs instead?

Comment: But I can't add a dialog to a frame can I? I have a main frame with a card layout and the different screens are panels added to that frame. Sorry but I am confused!